# react-beautiful-dnd: Prevent flicker when drag and drop a lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable, droppable, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using this react-beautiful-dnd library to be able to reorder lists. However, even though I'm able to drag and drop and re-order, **there is a flicker when I try to reorder lists**.
You can see in the video:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgSIA.gif)

Here is my code:
I added sorting to the array by order before mapping.

```
const Board = () => {
const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(null);

const lists = useSelector((state) => state.lists);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const classes = useStyles();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLists());
}, [currentId, dispatch]);

const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { destination, source, draggableId, type } = result;

    if(!destination) return;

    const droppableIdStart = source.droppableId;
    const droppableIdEnd = destination.droppableId;
    const droppableIndexStart = source.index;
    const droppableIndexEnd = destination.index;

    const newState = [...lists];

    // drag lists
    if(type === 'list') {
        const dragList = newState.splice(droppableIndexStart, 1);
        newState.splice(droppableIndexEnd, 0, ...dragList);
        
        // update order list to be index
        newState.forEach((list, index) => {
            list.order = index;
            dispatch(updateList(list._id , { ...list }));
        });
    }
    return newState;
}

// Arranging lists by order
const newArrange = (a,b) => {
    return (a.order - b.order);
}
lists.sort(newArrange);

return (
    <>
    <DragDropContext  onDragEnd={onDragEnd} >
        <div>
            <h1>Board</h1> 
            <Droppable droppableId="all-lists" direction="horizontal" type="list">
                { provided => (
                    <div className={classes.listContainer} {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef} >
                    { lists.map((list, index) => 
                        (user?.result?.googleId === list?.creator || user?.result?._id === list?.creator) ? 
                        <List key={list._id} title={list.title} cards={list.cards} currentId={list._id} index={index} /> :
                        null
                    )}
                        {addListFlag && (
                            <InputItem 
                                value={listData.title}
                                btnText={"Add list"} 
                                type={"list"} 
                                placeholder={"Enter a list title..."}
                                changedHandler={handleChange} 
                                closeHandler={closeHandlerBtn}
                                addItem={submitHandler}
                                />
                        )}
                        {!addListFlag && (
                            <AddBtn btnText={"Add another list"} type={"list"} handleClick={handleAddition} />
                        )}
                        {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                )}
            </Droppable>
        </div>
    </DragDropContext>
    </>
    )
}

export default Board;
```

Sample of data:

```
{
    _id: "6163cdd306d27b",
    title: "a",
    name: "first one",
    order: "0",
    cards:[
        {
            id: "0",
            text: "a1",
            _id: {_id: "61d0ca2c20d27e"}
        },
        {
            id: "1",
            text: "a2",
            _id: {_id: "616541ec90630"}
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            text: "a3",
            _id: {_id: "61606e609"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank :)

Answer (score 1):

It has probably todo with your `getLists()` call in the `useEffect` hook.

Is there an `async` function behind it? Do you get your lists from a server? If so, I suppose that `useEffect` is firing twice (once on drag end and once when it gets back the data from the backend or whatever `getLists` is doing), which leads to the flickering.

It would probably help to know what exactly `getLists` is.

Comment: "Its probably" its not an answer, please provide more specific answer.

Comment: This isn't an especially actionable comment. I agree more information is needed from the questioner.